Trying to edit existing Macro to change Input from a Numeric Field to a Text Field
I am new to Macros/VBAs and am trying to edit something my predecessor built out.  Essentially, I have a report from a CRM that exports 9 fields and then does a complex re-sorting. I want to replace one of those 9 fields (a numeric field called "Sort Priority") with a text field called "Course Session".  I think I have pinpointed where in the Macro it needs to be updated but have tried everything I can think of and can't figure out how to get it to properly update.
Thanks in advance.
Here is the code as is (I tried replacing the "Sort Priority" with "Course Session" and changing what I thought were integer functions to string but nothing worked).  Can't figure out what I am missing...
    Function FindQAReportStartColumn() As String
        For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("INPUT").Range("B1:B50")
            If InStr(1, CStr(cell.Value), "Sort Priority") > 0 Then
                FindQAReportStartColumn = cell.address
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next cell
    
        FindQAReportStartColumn = ""
    End Function


Not really sure we can answer this with the information given but you probably need to change the Range("B1:B50") to match the column you're looking for "Course Session" in. All this function is doing is finding "Sort Priority" in column B and then returning the address of the first cell it encounters with that string.

Thank you for the reply @Warcupine.  I thought there was something in the line below that would need to be updated because "Course Session" is text and this seems to be looking for a number (>0)
If InStr(1, CStr(cell.Value), "Sort Priority") > 0 Then

No, it is looking for the string Sort Priority in a cell's value and if that string appears then instr returns >0, the index of the string where it appears. if it isn't in the cell then instr returns 0 and it moves to the next cell.

You could just search the sheet for that string
Function FindQAReportStartColumn() As String

    Dim rng As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("INPUT").Cells
        Set rng = .Find("Course Session", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            FindQAReportStartColumn = ""
        Else
            FindQAReportStartColumn = rng.Address
        End If
    End With
    
End Function

